# jVectorMap - disable hover over country

Tags: jquery, css, jvectormap

I am using `jVectorMap` library and its working fine. But i don't want to show country name when mouse hover over the map.

```
// worldMap is the container
  $('#worldMap').vectorMap({
                    map: 'world_mill_en',
                    backgroundColor : 'transparent',
                    zoomOnScroll: false,
                    zoomButtons : false
    });
```

Currently its showing country name when we hover over the map. I want do disable this functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/3xZ28/238/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3xZ28/243/

```
onRegionLabelShow: function(e, el, code){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: create a jsfiddle please. I will try to provide some help. ;)

Comment: i have added a jsfiddle, please have a look at it. Also, `onRegionOver` is not working.

Comment: One more time edited my answer - this solution can messup  some of primary functions of this vector map so be careful.

Comment: thnx, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Is there anyway to change the background color of labels which shows in hover on markers. See http://jsfiddle.net/3xZ28/244/ . I want to change its background color of "San Francisco" to green.

Comment: .jvectormap-label {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

Comment: thnx again, but can do it while initializing the object.

Comment: There is event that is triggered upon hover on marker:  onMarkerLabelShow: function (e, el, code) {
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log(e, el, code);
     },

Comment: i think, css is a good approach to do that as suggested by you.

Comment: As of recent versions the function is now onRegionTipShow

Answer (score 11):

Old post, but as of v2.0.3, the event, `onRegionLabelShow`, has been changed to `onRegionTipShow`. Same goes for `onMarkerLabelShow` = `onMarkerTipShow`

```
onRegionTipShow: function (e, label, code) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After, taking help from @Mr.TK answer and further googling. I found the solution:

```
$('#worldMap').vectorMap({
     map: 'world_mill_en',
     backgroundColor: 'green',
     normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
     zoomOnScroll: false,
     zoomButtons: false,
     regionStyle: {
         hover: {
             "fill-opacity": 1
         }
     },
     onRegionLabelShow: function (e, el, code) {
         e.preventDefault();
     },
     markers: [{
         latLng: [37.7833, -122.4167],
         name: 'San Francisco'
     }]
 });
```

This is what, i am looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/3xZ28/244/